# propagate operating system variable in apache server

Tags: apache, environment-variables

I'm trying to read the operating system variable `HOMEPATH` from apache but the `getenv()` doesn't work in the browser but works in command line.

I have read several articles and they say it's a permission issue. But is there a way to propagate the operating system variable to be an apache env variable when apache starts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are on linux, and if you aren't I'm just posting this here for record (my search was fruitless, I'm on CentOS 6.5)

From what I understand, there's no way to provide apache any direct access to the environment variables including variables from the environment of the user that started the apache process and global environment variables you've specified within /etc/profile.d startup scripts.

Since I'm using bash, I have a variables.bashrc file that I source from my ~/.bashrc.  This variables.bashrc declares my user environment variables.  Within my apache startup script (/etc/init.d/httpd) I have added a line

```
. /path/to/variables.bashrc
```

that sources the same variables as my user has access to.  This makes these environment variables available to apache.

Apache may receive the variables but it can also block the variables unless you explicitly say to pass them on to your scripts.  This uses [mod_env](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html) so you must ensure this module is loaded  So you'll have to add

```
PassEnv VARIABLE_NAME
```

to the directory/virtual host you are configuring.  For example...

```
<Directory "/path/to/cgi/scripts/">
   AllowOverride None
   Options None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   PassEnv VARIABLE_NAME
</Directory>
```

This will make it available to your CGI scripts, or whatever script may be trying to access environment variables.

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant way to solve this, so I would be interested to see what other people have done to solve this issue... perhaps some automated way (mod_something) to make these variables visible.

Thanks.